# How can I add and calculate additional charges on stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

How can I make the VAT of service fee become $25? It seems it's getting the value from the total amount. I just added a tax code from the stripe dashboard directly and it seems the calculation is wrong.

The total would be $5525 since the service fee VAT is based on the service fee not on the total amount.

- Total amount = 5000
- Service fee 10% = 500
- VAT service fee 5% of the service fee = 25

But stripe give me this calculation. What I did was adding tax rates in the dashboard. The only one I got right is the service fee not the service fee VAT which is based on the service fee.

[[image: total sum]

I tried it by adding a stripe tax rates and calculations and it seems the VAT from the service fee is not correct.

Comment: It seems like you would need to set the tax rate for the VAT service fee to be 25$. The total amount would be 5525$, with a service fee of 500$ and a VAT service fee of 25$.

Comment: yeah @James how could I do it. Should I add it as a separate product since in the stripe dashboard I cant set it based on the service fee percentage

Comment: do you know how could I set it up on stripe? @James

Comment: Did you call it 'VAT of service fee" but it's actually the VAT of the price?  $250 is 5% of 5000.

Answer (score 1):

In my comment I suggested you need to set the VAT service fee to 25$ because your question seemed to indicate you had already worked through that a bit.

Here's a walkthrough on how to do it:

- Go to the Stripe dashboard and click on "Settings".
- Click on "Taxes".
- Click on "Add Tax Rate".
- In the "Name" field, enter a name for your
  custom tax rate.
- In the "Percentage" field, enter 5%.
- In the "Applies to" field, select "Service Fee".
- Click on "Save".

Once created, it will be applied to all service fees charged on your Stripe account. In your example, the total amount would be $5525.

How the calculation works:

- Total amount: $5000
- Service fee: 10% = $500
- VAT service fee: 5% of the service fee = $25
- Total: $5525

Comment: I tried this but the calculation is what I mentioned from above. I added two tax rates the VAT and the service fee